# Could not Load Configuration PandasAI and Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am having an issue for some reason and I absolutely cannot find a solution for it - I have followed many examples and guides and all of them say the same thing - which is not working for me. Only difference is that I am using Google Palm instead of OpenAI. I am using Google Colab. Any ideas?

Heres my code

```
!pip install pandas pandasai
!pip install google.generativeai

import pandas as pd
from pandasai import SmartDataframe
from pandasai.llm import GooglePalm

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "country": ["United States", "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Spain", "Canada", "Australia", "Japan", "China"],
    "gdp": [19294482071552, 2891615567872, 2411255037952, 3435817336832, 1745433788416, 1181205135360, 1607402389504, 1490967855104, 4380756541440, 14631844184064],
    "happiness_index": [6.94, 7.16, 6.66, 7.07, 6.38, 6.4, 7.23, 7.22, 5.87, 5.12]
})

llm = GooglePalm(api_key="my-key")
sdf = SmartDataframe(df, config={"llm": llm})
```

And the error is

> ERROR:pandasai.config:Could not load configuration Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandasai/config.py", line 19,
> in load_config
> with open(find_closest("pandasai.json"), "r") as f:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandasai/helpers/path.py",
> line 37, in find_closest
> return os.path.join(find_project_root(filename), filename)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandasai/helpers/path.py",
> line 29, in find_project_root
> raise ValueError("Could not find the root folder of the project.") ValueError: Could not find the root folder of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Above code works for me

```
!pip install pandasai
!pip install google.generativeai
import pandas as pd
from pandasai import SmartDataframe
from pandasai.llm import GooglePalm

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "country": ["United States", "United Kingdom", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Spain", "Canada", "Australia", "Japan", "China"],
    "gdp": [19294482071552, 2891615567872, 2411255037952, 3435817336832, 1745433788416, 1181205135360, 1607402389504, 1490967855104, 4380756541440, 14631844184064],
    "happiness_index": [6.94, 7.16, 6.66, 7.07, 6.38, 6.4, 7.23, 7.22, 5.87, 5.12]
})

llm = GooglePalm(api_key="key")
sdf = SmartDataframe(df, config={"llm": llm})
sdf.chat('Which are the 5 happiest countries?')
```

[My Colab Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOgqV.png)
above code is working fine for me here I suggest couple of changes

1. Install Python 3.10
2. Create a new env